# Mongodb aggregate match and group documents, with additional check

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

So I have 2 models: Question and Answer.

Answer has: questionId, userId, answer (String).

I need an aggregation pipline that will:

1. match all answers by questionId
2. see if the current user already voted (is his id in matched documents)
3. group answers and count them

I implemented 1 and 3 like this:

```
const q = ObjectId('5d6e52a68558b63fb9302efd');
const user = ObjectId('5d0b3f7daceeb50c477b49e0');

Answer.aggregate([
    { $match: { questionId: q } },
    { $group: { _id: '$answer', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
])
```

I am missing a step between those 2 aggregation pipelines, where I would iterate thru matched documents, and check if userId matches user.

I would like to get some object like this:

```
{
     didIVote: true,
     result: [ { _id: 'YES', count: 5 }, { _id: 'NO', count: 2 } ]
}
```

Or maybe even like this:

```
[
    { _id: 'YES', count: 5, didIVote: true },
    { _id: 'NO', count: 2, didIVote: false },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the `$group` stage, create an array with the users that voted
  for each answer.
- Add an aditional `$project` stage to check if the user is in the array.

```
    const q = ObjectId('5d6e52a68558b63fb9302efd');
    const user = ObjectId('5d0b3f7daceeb50c477b49e0');

    Answer.aggregate([
      { $match: { questionId: q } },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$answer',
          count: { $sum: 1 },
          voted: { $addToSet: "$userId" }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          count: 1,
          didIVote: { $in: [ user, "$voted" ] },
        }
      }
    ]);
```